# How can i enable the upload of large file on my Nodejs app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, large-files

I have a Nodejs+Angular app and i deploy it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In my app i have an image upload and  evrything works correctly excpet for large file images. I have some configurations for this:

- On my backend i use multer to upload images and i set the files limits on 10 MB

`module.exports = multer({storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 }}).single('image');`

- I also have a config file named '01_files.config' that i deploy whit the app whit this code

`files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 20M;`

Everything works on my local machine, but when i deploy the app it gives me a 'CORS error' when i try to upload image largest then 1MB (default size limit of multer).

I'm new of AWS configuration so i need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file "proxy.config" in the ".elasticbeanstalk" directory

```
files:
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
          server 127.0.0.1:3020;
          keepalive 256;
      }

  server {
      client_max_body_size 1G;
      ...
      ...
      ...
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

And use middleware like this:

```
const upload = multer({
  limits: { fileSize: 52428800 }
}).single('image');
```